# Code improvement

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Нужна помощь очень скилованных js людей. Мое тестовое задание завернули с комментариями "очень тяжелый код, есть дублирование кода, глобальная видимость используется и т.д.". Я сам не смог найти таких косяков. Можете поревьюить и прокомментировать косяки в конкретных местах?

```
ссылки на файлы:
```

[ссылка на архив](https://yadi.sk/d/xxEAOE0ukk66m)
[app.js](http://jsfiddle.net/9tc6xcLx/)

```
(() => {
    "use strict";

    window.App = _.extend({
        start() {
            _.defer(() => {
                Backbone.history.start({
                    pushState: true,
                    root: '/tz_utkin/'
                })
            });

            this.registerEvents();
        },

        registerEvents() {
            $(document).on('click', 'a[href]:not(.external)', e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                Router.navigate($(e.currentTarget).attr('href'), {trigger: true});
            })
        }
    }, Backbone.Events);

    App.start();
})();
```

[helpers.js](http://jsfiddle.net/yrmfjb1w/)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    window.Helpers = {
        object_loaded: function(name) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if(window[name]) {
                    resolve();
                }
                var i=0, interval = setInterval(() => {
                    if(window[name]) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        resolve();
                    } else if(i++ > 300) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        reject();
                    }
                }, 50);
            })
        },

        objects_loaded: function(objects = []) {
            var promise = new Promise(resolve => resolve());
            return objects.reduce((promise, name) => promise.then(() => this.object_loaded(name)), promise)
        }
    };
})();
```

[router.js](http://jsfiddle.net/n0988fgm/)

```
(() => {
"use strict";

let Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '': 'person',
        'person/:id': 'person'
    },

    person(id) {
        Helpers.objects_loaded(['PersonsCollection', 'PersonsPageView']).then(() => {
            let persons = new PersonsCollection();
            let view = new PersonsPageView({collection: persons});
            persons.on('sync', () => {
                document.all['content'].innerHTML = view.render(id);
            });
            persons.fetch();
        })
    }
});

window.Router = new Router();
```

})();

[personsPageView.js](https://jsfiddle.net/5yrLmwbj/)

```
(() => {
"use strict";

window.PersonsPageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    render(id) {
        id = id || 2;
        let template = Handlebars.compile(TemplatesStorage.get('#personsPage'));
        let context = {
            body: new PersonBodyView({model: this.collection.get(id)}).render(),
            bottom: new PersonsNavigationView({collection: this.collection}).render(id)
        };
        return template(context);
    }
})
```

})();

[personBodyView.js](http://jsfiddle.net/qqb5qpLx/)

```
(() => {
"use strict";

window.PersonBodyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    render() {
        let template = Handlebars.compile(TemplatesStorage.get('#personBody'));
        return template(this.model.toJSON());
    }
})
```

})();

[personsNavigationView.js](http://jsfiddle.net/zz0vgc3y/)
[personsPaginationView.js](http://jsfiddle.net/b7fxtuzz/)
[templatesStotage.js](http://jsfiddle.net/pthuq1dh/)
[personsPage.tpl.js](http://jsfiddle.net/y7dpkupr/)

Comment: Код должен быть в самом вопросе, а не на стороннем сайте. Если кода там тысячи и тысячи строк, то пожалейте других и выберите из кода только действительно проблемные участки.

Comment: там не много строк, но код разбит на файлы. + Как я написал выше, сам я не могу выделить проблемные участки.

Comment: можно было, хотя бы, само задание написать

Comment: 2015 год, люди сорсы архивами распространяют. Я бы такого человека на работу точно не взял )

Comment: @Suvitruf, а вам шашечки или ехать? :-D

Comment: я подумал, что само задание не имеет значения, так как претензии не к тому, что код делает не то - а к тому, что сам код тяжелый по мнению того кто составлял задание

Comment: Выложите хотя бы "app.js" - он мне уже не нравится :-D

Comment: @woland если там несколько файлов, то так и выложите их: "название файла, его код", "название файла, его код".

Comment: @Regent, их там куча :-) На самом деле хватило бы пары

Comment: @woland, а у вас, случайно, нет синтаксической ошибки в `PersonsPage.js`? в метод extend какой-то странный объект передаете

Comment: @woland, не ссылки, а сам текст, который в файлах

Comment: @Grundy { render(id){/*code*? } } <-  вы про это? это синтаксис es6. Код полностью рабочий

Comment: я выложил ссылки на jsfiddle, чтобы можно было кинуть ссылку на этот файл с комментами проблемных мест

Comment: прям первый вопрос: что такое _`_`_? Зачем в вашем случае IIFE если вы все равно все в window складываете? почему в одном месте используете синтаксис ES5, а в другом ES6? Почему добавляете в `window` а используете из глобальной области?

Comment: _ - это underscore. Синтаксис es6 везде.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32151/discussion-between-grundy-and-woland).

Comment: @Grundy А чем по вашему отличается window от глобальной области?

Comment: @Darth, например тем, что это не всегда может быть одним и тем же :-)

Comment: Ну, в нодежс например это называется global. В браузере window. По русски - глобальная область. нет?

Comment: @Darth, нет, в nodejs - разделены понятия global и скоп модуля. Поэтому иногда можно ожидать что будет браться из global но на самом деле возьмется из модульного

Comment: здесь код который работает только в браузере. Так что глобальная область == window. Это не могут быть разные объекты

Comment: @Grundy А я думал что есть глобальная область и (локальный) скоп модуля.. нет? есть глобальная область и много глобальных областей скопов модуля? Или что вы хотите донести, я как то не пойму никак. В браузере тоже легко можно столкнутся ситуацией, когда криворучка ждет чего-то от window а получает от локального скопа, ноджсные модули тут ни при чем

Comment: @Darth, _In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope `var something` will define a **global variable**. In Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; `var something` inside an Node.js module will be local to that module._

Comment: @Grundy И? Тут написано, что модули ноджс имеют свой локальный скоп. Если вы будете писать например модули для require.js в браузере, там будет всё то же самое - `var something`  will be local to that module. И вообще мы от темы отклонились, расскажите мне лучше чем window от глобальной области видимости отличается.

Comment: @Grundy: конечно ехать, а на архивах далеко не уедешь.